# batch to copy pictures into folders based on their names

Tags: batch-file, directory

Is there any way to copy pictures from a folder into other existing folders? the existing folder path should be the parts of the picture names. I try to explain below with an example.

I have pictures in c:\test

```
a_aa_pic1.jpg
a_bb_pic1.jpg
a_bb_pic2.jpg
b_dd_pic1.jpg
```

I would like to copy this pictures into folders in c:\test2 where the folders are already exists and rename the files to pic1, pic2 etc.

```
c:\test2\a\aa\pic1.jpg
c:\test2\a\bb\pic1.jpg
```

etc.

I have found this below, which does something similar, but I'm not a batch guru..:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=&" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
         md "%%b&%%c" 2>nul
         copy "%%a" "%%b&%%c" >nul
      )
)
pause
```

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B *.jpg') do copy "%%a_%%b_%%c" "c:\test2\%%a\%%b\%%c"`

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution ;)